# how to make the mplfinance charts always display years

Tags: python-3.x, mplfinance

the mplfinance chart will only display years when the dates of the data are crossing different years (here 2014-2015) like:

[image]

otherwise, the dates on the chart will look like:

[image]

how to make the year information always be displayed on the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use kwarg `datetime_format=` when calling `mpf.plot()`.  So, for example, to get the format that you described above, do:

```py
mpf.plot(df,...,datetime_format="%Y-%b-%d")
```

See all of the available format codes here: https://strftime.org/